# These is no buffering,no playing and no exceptions when play a track

Tags: android, sdk, deezer

I used the android SDK(version v0.10.10) to play a track, but during the playing  there was no buffering,no playing,and also no exceptions. There are three SDK c libraries which are provided by Deezer,and i've tried all,and none works.How should i resolve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have an error message in the log cat view? Could you provide the coffee you're using to play a track. Also how do you include the c libraries in your project?

Answer (score 0):

When setting the player instance before DeezerConnect object has been authorised, music doesn't start playing, and no error is thrown.

When calling:

```
player = new DefaultPlayerFactory( application, deezerConnect, new WifiOnlyNetworkStateChecker() ).createPlayer();
```

Make sure, you have an authenticated **deezerConnect** object.